# Overriding pre-defined CSS style

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where there are images with predefined style in the css like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
   #content img  {
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   }
</STYLE>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#dddddd">
   <div id="content">
       <img src="image.gif" />
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For most of the images inside the page it's ok but in some cases I would like display images without the pre-defined style. Is it possible in some way? maybe with an inline style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class to images that you do not want to have this style.

```
#content img.noshadow{
  -moz-box-shadow: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
}
```

then offcourse your image would be `<img class="noshadow" src="image.gif" />`

Comment: I tried adding your class to the sample above and adding same image, but it doesn't work for me (chrome 13)

Comment: my bad, there shouldnt be a dash before -box-shadow, edited my answer

Comment: fixed it just replacing :0 with 0px 0px 0px. Thanks

Comment: weird, Id expect 0 to work here. It works fine on other css properties.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.  As you mentioned, an inline style is one option.  There are others.  You should read a bit about css precedence.

One possible link (first result on google, don't know about this site in general but the article looked okay):

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Answer (score 1):

Make a more specific CSS selector:

```
body #content img  {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an inline style in such cases. As shown below.

```
 <img src="image.gif" height="" width="" ... />
```

Hope this helps you!!